# How to check if first and last element in a list are identical (Language: Scheme)

Tags: scheme

I am writing a program in Scheme and having difficulty with this one part. Below is an example to make my question clear

(endsmatch lst) should return #t if the first element in the list is the same as the last element in the list and return #f otherwise.

For example:
(endsmatch '(s t u v w x y z)) should return: #f

and

(endsmatch (LIST 'j 'k 'l 'm 'n 'o 'j)) should return: #t

Here is what I have so far (just error handling). The main issue I am having is solving this **recursively**. I understand there are easier solutions that are not recursive but I need to solve this using recursion.

My code so far:

```
    (define (endsmatch lst)

       (if (not(list? lst))     
          "USAGE: (endsmatch [list])"

          (if (or (null? lst)
              (= (length lst) 1))
              #t

          (equal? ((car lst)) (endsmatch(car lst)))

    )))
```

I believe my code starting at "(equal? " is where it is broken and doesn't work. This is also where I believe recursion will take place. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to use a (recursive) helper function to do the looping:

```
(define (endsmatch lst)

  (define (helper no1 lst)
    (if (null? (cdr lst))
        (equal? no1 (car lst))
        (helper no1 (cdr lst))))

  (if (or (not (list? lst)) (null? lst))
      "USAGE: (endsmatch [list])"
      (helper (car lst) lst)))
```

The reason I pass `lst` and not `(cdr lst)` as the second argument in the last line is so that it also works for 1-element lists.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to use [KISS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) when programming. aka. "Keep it simple, stupid!"
With that regard I would have oped for:

```
(define (ends-match? lst)
  (or (null? lst)
      (equal? (car lst)
              (last lst))))
```

Now `last` we can define like this:

```
(define (last lst)
  (foldl (lambda (e a) e) last lst))
```

It's not perfect. It should signal an error if you pass an empty list, but in the `ends-match?` you check for this and thus it's not a problem.